# Android Navigation Component unresolved reference

Tags: android, kotlin, android-architecture-navigation

I've just changed platform from windows to mac, and when I try to build my app I get this message:

```
Unresolved reference. None of the following candidates is applicable because of receiver type mismatch:
public fun `Activity;`.findNavController(viewId: Int): `NavController;` defined in androidx.navigation
public fun `View;`.findNavController(): `NavController;` defined in androidx.navigation
```

The error is in that line:

```
bSettingsLogout.findNavController().navigate(R.id.authenticationActivity)
```

On Windows I've used older 3.3 canary version, but on the developer site nothing changed about navigation components.

I'm not sure if it a mac, or a Android Studio canary 6 error.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are 2 implementations for `findNavController`:  
`public static NavController findNavController (View view)` and 
`public static NavController findNavController (Activity activity, int viewId)` 
but you use

```
findNavController()
```

you' re missing the needed parameters

Comment: But it worked yesterday, and I've followed the implementation manual. O.o
Thanks, I'm gonna check it.

Comment: findNavController needs an activity or fragment as 1st parameter: `Navigation.findNavController(myActivity, R.id.nav_host)`

Comment: @mTak since the OP is using Kotlin, there are some extension functions provided in the Kotlin version of the navigation libraries, such as `fun View.findNavController(): NavController = Navigation.findNavController(this)` which mean that you can just call `findNavController()` on a `View` object, as opposed to passing the `View` into a static function

Comment: mTak is right. Upgrading gradle to 3.3.0.alpha6 causes, that View.findnavController() doesn't work but Navigation.findnavcontroller(View) works. (@mTak, if you also write the gradle issue to your answer i'll accept it)

Comment: @BenEzard I guess you' re right. I've only used the Java version.

Comment: @PéterKovács the gradle case did not occur to me so I'm fine

Comment: That's strange, because I've downgraded the gradle and View.findnavcontroller worked as before.

Comment: @PéterKovács it seems that Ben Ezard is right, but since this is Kotlin I can't be sure

Comment: Which _implementation_ line should be added into module `build.grade` for `public static NavController findNavController (View)`?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it just appears to be a bug with the latest version of Android Studio Canary. At least, rolling back to a previous Canary build solved the issue for me

I'm running Windows, so it's not a Mac issue

Answer (score 0):

on my case i had 2 different navigation file with same id and i've changed one of them, clear, build again, worked for me

```
<navigation 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:id="@+id/nav_graph">
```